# WAMP $_POST suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, post, wamp

So i think i unchecked something on the WAMP and for the love of god i don't know which because the $_POST is not working anymore.

I know my code is not the problem because it was working until the incident happened.

here a scenario:

```
if ($_POST) {
 var_dump($_POST);
}
```

prints an empty array

but if i used this code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 echo "here";
}
```

it successfully prints.

i tried using $_GET which works but not with $_POST.

what did i do wrong? D:

EDIT: Form

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align:center;">
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username..." class="inputText" style="margin-bottom:5px;" />
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..." class="inputText" /><br /><br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

EDIT: i tried my luck from all of your comments and ended up with reinstalling my WAMP and it fixed it, but the fact that i did not know what was causing it makes it more frustating. thanks guys. happy coding!

Comment: Umm...$_POST _is_ going to be an empty array unless you submit the form.

Comment: check the "post_max_size" directive in php.ini.

Comment: yes of course, i was just assuming the form was submitted, again this is not my code problem because all of my previous works that submits as post is not working anymore.

Comment: @MirceaSoaica it is set 8M and enabled..

Comment: Try `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){var_dump($_POST);}` and tell us what that prints. An empty Array?

Comment: @AndreschSerj yes it's empty..

Comment: So the used method is `post` yet your `$POST` array is empty. Try checking `$_REQUEST` to see if any data was send.
Also try using your browsers web developer toolkit to inspect your HTTP request if possible (*install firefox webdeveloper plugin or just hit F12 on Chrome*)

Comment: Did you change this variable in `php.ini`? `variables_order = "GPCS"` If you removed the `P` that might explain it!

Comment: @AndreschSerj tried var_dump($_REQUEST) prints an empty array also, used chrome devtool and it say METHOD is POST

Comment: Sure post_max_size is 8M and not 8MB? This seemed to be causing the same issue with me some time back.

Comment: @KanishkDudeja it's **8M**

Comment: Also have error_reporting on. That might tell us the issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i did not, it is still valued GPCS..

Comment: @KanishkDudeja it is on..

Comment: Please post the complete `<form.....` tag from the html code. Edit your question to include this info, dont add it to the comments

Comment: WAMP has nothing to do with your issue. Copy & paste your code here.

Comment: @lubosdz how come all my previous work that i have not edited many weeks ago does not work anymore also?

Comment: Recommendation: Post your php.ini files in a pastebin, and include the URL. We may be able to help a bit better if we know your configuration.

Comment: Have you tried setting an enctype on the <form..> tag. `<form method="post" action="login.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Isolate the error - either run script under different webserver to confirm that Wamp is the bad ass here or simplify your script down to the most elementary scholar example until it works correctly - and then add back line by line your script. Try reinstalling WAMP or switching to another PHP version (without reinstalilng WAMP).